# Google tag manager return 404 for link of second ID measurement

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

In my google tag manager account I created two measurement IDs for google analytics.
So my structure is this:

TAG MANAGER container code: GTM-00001 |
Analytics Code 1: G-00001 |
Analytics Code 2: G-00002

When I go to copy and paste the tag manager code snippet into my site I notice that tag manager calls up two links:

```
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.org/gtag/js?id=G-00001&l=dataLayer&cx=c"></script>
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.org/gtag/js?id=G-00002&l=dataLayer&cx=c"></script>
```

The second link in the console returns this error:

```
net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

What could it depend on?